# Bootstrap 4 : '.flex-column' working but not '.justify-content-center'

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on some old code and trying to place the content properly on my page but I'm facing a problem : My flex properties are working but not the '.justify-content-...'.

Here's my code :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<h3 class="titre-jumbotron-video text-center mb-2 mt-3">Parameters</h3>

<div class="max-min d-flex flex-column mt-1 mb-4 mx-auto" style="width: 95%">

<fieldset>

  <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-start">
        <div>
          <p>Some content</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Other type of content : </label>
          <input type="checkbox">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
        <img id="apercuGraphe" src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/504/739/5c0.jpg" alt="Apercu Graphe" width="200px">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-end">
        <div>
          <label>Content 1 : </label>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Content 2 : </label>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Content 3 : </label>
          <select>
            <option value="auto">Automatic</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</fieldset>

  </div>
```

I think that I'm misunderstanding something but I don't know what.

*PS: Expand the snippet to see it on a big screen.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `align-items-center` and `align-items-end`...

https://www.codeply.com/go/icRQlWbCDq

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-start">
        <div>
          <p>Some content</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Other type of content : </label>
          <input type="checkbox">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <img id="apercuGraphe" src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/504/739/5c0.jpg" alt="Apercu Graphe" width="200px">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-end justify-content-end">
        <div>
          <label>Content 1 : </label>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Content 2 : </label>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Content 3 : </label>
          <select name="axeX" id="selectAxeX" class="select-no-ui">
            <option value="auto">Automatic</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ok ! Is that because I'm using flex-column so it's not justify-content but align-items ?

Answer (score 1):

You have three classes align-items-start align-items-center align-items-end

Obviously, as the term suggests. You would now how this three classes works.